# can a DPDA have two transition to different states when you pop a different symbol?

Tags: pushdown-automata

I have a question about the DPDA. Is it possibly to have two transitions that read the same input but do different in the stack?

An example would be A transition from q1 to q2 where I read input ( pop v and push nothing to the stack. And the second transition is from q1 to q3 where I read input ( pop x and push nothing to the stack. Notice that x and v is diffrent symbols

I understand that the stack won't be confused because it depends on what is the top most symbol in the stack. So I think this is fine in a DPDA. Am i thinking right?

Comment: Please check the [formal definition of a DPDA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_pushdown_automaton#Formal_definition). Note that the transition is based on the current state, input, and top stack symbol.